# How to get the last x number of splistitems changed for a SPWeb

Tags: caml-query, spquery

I'm trying to pull back the last x number of list items in all non-hidden lists for a given web.

My original code would go through all lists and run the following code:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name =\"Modified\" Ascending=\"FALSE\"/></OrderBy>";
query.RowLimit = (uint)this.ItemsToDisplay;

switch(list.BaseType)
{
    case SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary:
        query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
        break;
    default:

        break;
}

SPListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
```

effectively getting the last x items modified from each list and then I would put all of them into a List and sort, then taking the bottom x items.

This code was really slow (sometimes taking 20-30 seconds) so I decided to go down the route of using the ChangeLog.

Now i'm doing this code:

```
SPChangeQuery query = new SPChangeQuery(false, false);
query.Item = true;
query.Delete = false;
query.Add = true;
query.Update = true;
query.ChangeTokenStart = new SPChangeToken(SPChangeCollection.CollectionScope.Web, Web.ID, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(-14));
query.ChangeTokenEnd = new SPChangeToken(SPChangeCollection.CollectionScope.Web, Web.ID, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());

SPChangeCollection changes = Web.GetChanges(query);
```

which works well in dev but has issues in prod.  It turns out that in prod since we run MOSS and profiles are synced, I get 1000's of changes that are occuring in the user information list.  So right now since the GetChanges method only pulls items in chunks of 1000, i have to use the lastchangetoken and call getchanges several times and then sort through 1000's of items just to get at the one's I want.

First question:  Does anyone know how to exclude hidden lists or certain lists from a SPChangeQuery?

Second question:  Is there a faster / better way of doing this?  I thought about using Auditing to get the data since I have that turned on for all of our site collections but I haven't gone down that path yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the SPSiteDataQuery?? Has anyone tried that before?  I assume that will security trim the data it returns?

Comment: This guy just seems to be checking each list that is returned and determining whether to continue or not.  http://blog.sharepoint2007.com.au/2009/06/23/using-spchangequery-in-a-new-site-spweb/
The downside to the changelog still seems to be the lack of security trimming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPListItems is not included in auditlog (per design due to performance issues) so you cant use auditing if you are looking for list items.

I would probably go for [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) (as you mention yourself) which usually performs best for site-wide queries.

Another option would be the [GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx) web service which often i surprisingly fast...

A third option would be [ProcessBatchData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.processbatchdata.aspx) using the Display method, if it can be tweaked to deliver the data you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the options.  I'll try to give those a go.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried the SPSiteDataQuery and on paper it seemed like it would work.  But unfortunately it is kind of buggy.  If I specified the lists to return it would only return generic lists.  If I specified to return document libraries, it would return ones that I didn't want.  The GetListItems seemed to only be for a single list and that's not much different than my SPQuery original code.  ProcessBatchData also seemed like I would have to aggregate data from multiple lists.

I ended up going back to my original code and worked out a way to lazy load the data through ajax.  

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do it at a more granular level using SPList.GetChanges()? Obviously you'd have to do some merging of resultsets, but you'd probably be working with fewer overall change items. I guess a big factor would be how many lists you have, as this would be tied to how many merge operations your code would have to do..

Comment: Yea, I thought about that but i'm not sure how much faster that is going to be over my original code that does the spquery.  Thanks!

Comment: I ended up having to provide an option in my webpart to switch to your suggestion because of the list view threshhold stuff in 2010.

Comment: Your solution also ended up being faster in some cases but slower in others.  I think because I couldn't figure out a good way to limit or sort the number of items returned.